# looking to create a hosted solution

Tags: php, dns, e-commerce, hosted-app

I am in the early stages of thinking through a product I am looking to develop, the product is a hosted e-commerce solution. What kind of things do I need to think about when allowing users to register there own domain names? Hows does that even work? I know I can do subdomains, but no idea how a users own domain would work on the hosted solution?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple domains on a single host using virtual hosts, as supported by [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html). See the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/) for setting up virtual hosts for Apache httpd for example (you may use some other web server).

You probably don't want to get involved with the actual domain registration: users should register the domain with an established [domain registrar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) and configure the [A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) to point to your server.

All a user would then do is specify their domain name and you'd update Apache's httpd.conf (or equivalent config file) appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the easy way out - A resellers account. I had one before, it was easy to use and setup. The only problem I had was there are extra fees if you want people to register domains though your website. It's worth the money if your going to make it back.

I used JustHost.com, there pricing is fair but there e-mail system and cPanel are out-dated. E-mail is fine if you use POP3 or IMAP.

Good Luck,
CwTechies